# Getting Error: read ECONNRESET while trying to send code through Postman Desktop agent

Tags: mongodb, rest, mongoose, postman-collection-runner

I'm trying to send data through Postman Desktop Agent to localhost:27017/articles. My mongod server is running. Tried hotspot on my phone as well as my home internet connection.   I dont think the internet is the issue. I don't have a VPN nor do I require one. I'm 99% sure my code is correct. I'm getting in the Postman console "Error: read ECONNRESET"  As well, I scoured the internet for a solution but nothing to my situtation.

`

```
//jshint version:6

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let ejs = require('ejs');

//express setup
const app = express();

//EJS setup with express
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//body parser setup
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Mongoose setup
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

var db = {};
var settings = {
  reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
  autoReconnect: true
};
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", settings, function(err, dbref) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("Mongdb connected (new code)");
        db = dbref;
      } else {
        console.log("Error while connecting to mongDB" + err);
      }
  });
}

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String
});

const Article = mongoose.model("Article", articleSchema);

async function save(err){
  if (!err){
    const article = await article.save();
    console.log(article + " saved");
  }else{
    console.log(err);
  }
}








app.get("/articles", function(req, res) {
  Article.find(function(err, foundArticles) {
    if (!err) {
      res.send(foundArticles);
    } else {
      res.send(err)
    }

  });
});

app.post("/articles", function(req, res) {
  console.log("post request")
  console.log(req.body.title);
  console.log(req.body.content);

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

`

I tried calling the internet company to see if there was a proxy or something that i know nothing about that was blocking the transfer from Postman to localhost... I tried error catching in my mongoose.connect(...) function. No problems there. Seems to running fine as you can see in the screenshot of Hyperterminal loaded up. I tried restarting mongod server.    I read the ECONNRESET error on the postman community portal. I didnt see anything I needed to change. Restful application working on localhost:3000

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: The error says "Syntax error: missing argument after )". You write "I'm 99% sure my code is correct." - look for the missing percent! Your IDE should support you in finding it.

Comment: Sorry about the pictures. Didnt know that thought I was doing something special that no one did. but read through the docs understand now. Also, the parenthesis is fixed. The picture showed that the server was restarted with no errors. again, sorry about the pictures and appreciate your help